# Wordpress PHP: List categories without links?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress 3.01, and would like to list a number of child categories within a parent in this format. Without links.

{ 'cat1' , 'cat2' }

Is this possible?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
this call seems like the right one, but I can't figure out how to list them without turning off links

Thanks,
Azeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `get_categories()` function. This returns an array of all categories. There is a codex article on it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

```
$categories = get_categories();
$parent_id = 25; //the id of the parent category

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->parent == $parent_id) {
        echo "'" . $category->name . "',"
    }
}
```

That should work - let me know how you go. Someone else might have a better solution but I've used similar solutions to this and it has worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `Walker_Category` class and assign it to the `walker` attribute in the `$args` for `wp_list_categories($args);`.

By doing this, you have the ability to override how the links are rendered. In your case, you could probably just copy the code from `Walker_Category` and remove the part that wraps the category name in an anchor (`<a>`).

Maybe there's an easier way; I don't know -- I'm a WP n00b.

Here is one example I scouted out for you:

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-modify-lists-like-categories-and-blogroll-in-wordpress